# flag record as delete instead of deleting the record from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

i want to know how to proceed to flag records as deleted instead of physically deleting the record from the database. I never came across such a thing before. Is there any tutorial i can follow?

Comment: If you want to keep all records could you not just add a boolean field to the table to flag "deleted" records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extra boolean field in your table to denote if the entry is valid or not.

```
TableName(<Your Fields>,Valid)
```

Valid =1 , then it is present.

Valid =0, then it is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to add a new BOOL column to the table like `enabled` with a default value of `1`.

Then `UPDATE table_name SET enabled = 0` when you would like to "delete" the row.

And filter out "deleted" rows in your queries like:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ... AND enabled = 1`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing intrinsic in MySQL to flag a record as deleted - but you can add your your own column to describe the state - you just need need to remember to exclude it from your queries. The complication arises when you try to insert a row with unique/primary keys matching your deleted record; you'll need to add a trigger to amend the state. Really a simpler option is to just delete the data in the first place (you don't say what you're trying to achieve by not deleting the row)